# Count NaN per row with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to output the frequency of my First_Name column in my data frame; per row. So far I was successful in doing so but I would also like to know how to count both NaN values and Non-NaN values per row.

Below is a data frame with two columns: First_Name and Favorite_Color.
I wanted to see if I can get a count of the First_Name column. When I output the code, I was only able to get a count of Non-NaN values. Is there a way to also include a count of NaN values and have that to a part of the data frame?

```py
import pandas as pd

d = 
{
'First_Name': ["Jared", "Lily", "Sarah", "Bill", "Bill", "Alfred", None], 
'Favorite_Color': ["Blue", "Blue", "Pink", "Red", "Yellow", "Orange", "Red"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['countNames'] = df.groupby('First_Name')['First_Name'].transform('count')

print(df)
```

I expected to get a count of both NaN and non NaN values but I only got a count for Non-NaN values.

## Edit: Thank you Everyone!

I really enjoyed reading everyone's answer, it's really interesting to see so many different solutions to solving this! I think SH-SF's answer is nice because it's a bit more easier to understand but does need to make use of the numpy library for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, this should fulfill your needs.

```
nasum=df['First_Name'].isnull().sum()
df['countNames'] = df.groupby('First_Name')['First_Name'].transform('count').replace(np.nan,nasum)
```

or, as suggested by ALollz, below code will also provide the same result

```
df['countNames'] = df.groupby('First_Name')['First_Name'].transform('count').fillna(nasum)
```

**Input**

```
       First_Name   Favorite_Color
0         Jared     Blue
1          Lily     Blue
2         Sarah     Pink
3          Bill     Red
4          Bill     Yellow
5          Alfred   Orange
6          None     Red
7          None     Pink
```

**Output**

```
     First_Name     Favorite_Color  countNames
0         Jared          Blue        1.0
1         Lily           Blue        1.0
2         Sarah          Pink        1.0
3         Bill           Red         2.0
4         Bill           Yellow      2.0
5         Alfred         Orange      1.0
6         None           Red         2.0
7         None           Pink        2.0
```

Comment: Same idea; I like the syntax of `.fillna(nasum)`, since it reads a bit more plainly :D. That also supports `downcast='int'` as an arg since these are all integers. +1

Comment: Wouldn't `df.fillna(nasum)` fill NA in all columns with `nasum`? I wanted to avoid that scenario.

Comment: Added the solution with `.fillna(nasum)` as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df['countNames'] = df.fillna(-1).groupby('First_Name')['First_Name'].transform('count')

First_Name Favorite_Color  countNames
0      Jared           Blue           1
1       Lily           Blue           1
2      Sarah           Pink           1
3       Bill            Red           2
4       Bill         Yellow           2
5     Alfred         Orange           1
6       None            Red           1
```

Answer (score 1):

One "quick" way  to solve is by casting as string :

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
'First_Name': ["Jared", "Lily", "Sarah", "Bill", "Bill", "Alfred", None], 
'Favorite_Color': ["Blue", "Blue", "Pink", "Red", "Yellow", "Orange", "Red"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['First_Name'] = df['First_Name'].astype(str)



df['countNames'] = df.groupby('First_Name')['First_Name'].transform('count')

print(df)

  First_Name Favorite_Color  countNames
0      Jared           Blue           1
1       Lily           Blue           1
2      Sarah           Pink           1
3       Bill            Red           2
4       Bill         Yellow           2
5     Alfred         Orange           1
6       None            Red           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need transform here. Just use `map` and `value_counts` on temp dataframe `df1` as follows

```
df1 = df.astype(str)
df['countNames'] = df1['First_Name'].map(df1['First_Name'].value_counts())

Out[802]:
  First_Name Favorite_Color  countNames
0      Jared           Blue           1
1       Lily           Blue           1
2      Sarah           Pink           1
3       Bill            Red           2
4       Bill         Yellow           2
5     Alfred         Orange           1
6       None            Red           1
```